# Where does lost bits goes?

Tags: java, c++

I was studying the shift operators in java, the book says ' value << num ' ,
If value is int then after left shift operation , left bits are lost once the limit crosses the limit of int (31th position of int value) that I can understand,

My question is very simple where does the lost bits goes ?

Comment: It goes into the trash, it's completely removed...  Same as if you set the variable to 0.

Comment: It depends on the processor and the language. In Java it's lost. In C it goes into the processor's overflow bit, if there is one, and if you can find it. I used a language once that had a $OVERFLOW variable for the overflow bit: it was seriously useful for writing multiple-precision arithmetic.

Comment: (From Intel's Software Developer's Manual) SAL/SAR/SHL/SHR: Shifts the bits in the first operand (destination operand) to the left or right by the number of bits specified in the second operand (count operand). Bits shifted beyond the destination operand boundary are first shifted into the CF
flag, then discarded. At the end of the shift operation, the CF flag contains the last bit shifted out of the destination
operand.

Comment: Punch "bit bucket" into your favorite search engine. The origin is believed to be rhyming slang for a common English expression meaning, roughly, "whatever".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lost bits do not exist anymore. The lost bits are no longer in the register because they have been replaced with the new bits. The new bits are created as a result of the shift operation. The registers can only hold but so many bits so when the shift occurs, and the new bits are placed into the register, the lost bits do not exist anymore. There is nowhere for the lost bits to go. Think of the lost bits as falling off of a cliff.

There is an overflow flag, which is a register used to indicate an overflow has occurred, but according to wikipedia, bit-wise and shift operations can leave the flag undefined or cleared. Here is information on the overflow flag : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overflow_flag

Click here for info on java Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators [Java Bit Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)!

Comment: I don't see what Wikipedia has to do with it. Some processor shift into a carry bit, some don't. It isn't as though it was non-deterministic.